# Xamarin.Forms: prevent resize when keyboard appear on a specific entry

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have set Window.SetSoftInputMode on AdjustResize in Android native project. However, only when a specific entry gets focus, I need to disable both page resize and scroll when keyboard is showed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set the Soft Keyboard Input Mode on Android device on xamarin form app?

If yes, you can set the `Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` attached property to a value of the `WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` enumeration:

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
  ...
</Application>
```

Alternatively, it can be consumed from C# using the fluent API:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
...

App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

For more, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode .